# how to import fromPromise from RxJS 6.2.1 in node 10.4.1

Tags: node.js, rxjs, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to use `fromPromise` in a node.js script following the first example from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html (code also here: https://jsfiddle.net/btroncone/upy6nr6n/)

Since I'm using node 10.4.1, I can't use `import` but need to use `require` instead.

I was able to import `mergeMap` with this line:

```
var mergeMap = require('rxjs/operators').mergeMap;
```

instead of

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The problem is to import `fromPromise`. The example shows this line:

`import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';`

I tried all the following options without success:

```
var fromPromise = require('rxjs/observable/fromPromise');
var fromPromise = require('rxjs/observable/fromPromise').fromPromise;
var fromPromise = require('rxjs/observable');
var fromPromise = require('rxjs/observable').fromPromise;
var fromPromise = require('rxjs').fromPromise;
```

Comment: Did you try var fromPromise = require('rxjs').fromPromise;

Comment: `fromPromise` is now just `from` and is imported from `'rxjs'`.

Comment: Thanks @cartant. I solved the problem by using this line: `var from = require('rxjs').from;`

Answer (score 0):

You just use `require('rxjs').from;`. In rxjs@6 formpromise is no more exported.

Comment: That does not work, because node.js does not support `import` natively, or at least I could not make it work, but that's beyond this question. Thanks.

Comment: Above I have written typescript syntax you can convert into nodejs required syntax like you have mentioned in questions comment.I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As specified by @cartant, the answer is:

```
var from = require('rxjs').from;
```

`fromPromise` is now just `from`.